# Data is not updating to collection as required

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Iam trying to update my data using mongodb query in my nestjs project. But the data is not updating as required.

```
let school = await this.schoolModel.updateOne({ id: item.school, "exams.id": exam.id }, {
                            $set: {
                                "exams.$.terms": item.terms, "exams.$.exam": exam.id, 
                                "exams.$.subject": item.subject
                            }
                        })
```

Comment: "... not updating as required" - can you elaborate?

Comment: query is not updating the the collection. there is some problem in the query i think... could not figure it out!

Comment: And are you sure `item.school` matches the `id`?

Comment: yes, and also i have multiple conditions there is it the right way to put exams.id?

Comment: Yes, it looks ok - can you create a reproducible example on https://mongoplayground.net/?